# Creating multible bootable partitions on USB drive from terminal? (macOS)

Tags: macos, partitioning, terminal, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

I have a 64GB UBS flash drive, and I want to divide this in multiple partitions. Then I would like to put a different bootable volume on each partition, for example various USB/Live versions of different Linux distributions, or a separate Memtest86 image, or whatever.

And then I need to be able to boot from any of these bootable partitions. Either through selecting the particular partition from the computer's boot volume selection menu, or maybe through some multi-boot menu on the USB drive if there is such a thing (although I assume the former option makes more sense).

Upon searching I came across suggestions such as manually creating an MBR, or putting grub2 on the USB drive. But I don't know exactly what that is (other than a boot loader) or how to actually do that. My understanding in this area is limited so I don't know how to go from there.

I'd highly prefer do this 'manually', with some combination shell commands like `diskutil`, `gpt`, and `dd`, so I fully understand the entire process.

Assuming I have the ISOs for all the bootable images, how do I pull this off from the macOS terminal? Or just a bash terminal in general, but I'm on macOS where I don't have `gparted` for example.

I already know how do this with just a single bootable ISO, copying it to the *entire USB drive* (thus overwriting/deleting any previous partitions if they existed). But I can't seem to figure out how to do do this with multiple volumes/partitions on the same USB disk.

Comment: For macOS I'd find a multiboot usbcreator. If the iso's are compatible with grub's loopback device (most Ubuntu-derived os's are, plenty of others too), then you just copy the iso's to the usb and edit grub.cfg, only trick is finding what to put in grub.cfg, may have to dig through the iso. See [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/573898/129271) for info & links to ArchWiki & PenDriveLinux. [FYI just `dd`'ing the iso onto the usb isn't the best way, it wastes the rest of the usb's space and I don't think it will support a multiboot usb at all]